# Div position fixed on the top of web page

Tags: css, html, position

How to make a div to always appear at the top of a web page even when the paged is scrolled vertically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use CSS `position: fixed;`:

```
#topdiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

See jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/CXACT/1/

Answer (score 2):

`div#myDiv {position: fixed; top: 0px; ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Css :

```
#topdiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

You can also make with JQuery,

Just always take the scrolltop value and change the div top.

```
$("#topdiv").css("top", scrolltop);
```